# Django with python 2.7 utf-8 problems

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I have problems width encoding characters in (html) template. In my database there are results like :

1. Čaša
2. Šišanje

That words are in Croatian language. In my **settings.py** where LANGUAGE_CODE
I have set :
**LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr-HR'** also tryd with **LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr'**.
The problem is when database returns record in forms:

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all().filter(type_id="2"),
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker'}), label=('Kategorija'),
                                      initial='1', )
```

And all record for that field must be render in HTML page, as selectpicker.
When I try to load that page I get this error:

1. Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
2. Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0107' in position  ordinal not in range(128)

Python version : 2.7.9

Django version : 1.7.7

In my **models.py**, the model is :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_id = models.ForeignKey('CategoryType')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

I have also try with:

```
  class Category(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        type_id = models.ForeignKey('CategoryType')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Do you know any easy way to solve this problem, I know python 3 have better utf encoding, but I wanna stay on 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Ooooooo it works :D. Thak you soo much! @skyline75489

Comment: This is just hiding the problem. See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-August/091406.html for some discussion of possible side effects.

Comment: it's an awesome quick fix, but according to Peter's link this might have some very ugly side effects, tnx tho

Answer (score 3):

Change your `__str__` method to `__unicode__`.

The exception you're seeing comes from mixing encoded bytestrings with Unicode objects. To do that, Python 2.x tries to implicitly encode the Unicode objects using the default encoding and raises an exception if it can't. Thus, when your default encoding is ascii, `u'foo' + 'bar'` works, but `u'foo\u270c' + 'bar'` does not.

In Django, `CharField`s on model instances return Unicode objects. In Python 2.x, the `__str__` method is expected to return an encoded bytestring rather than a Unicode object, so by returning `name` un-encoded you're causing Django to mix Unicode objects with bytestrings.

You could also fix it by explicitly encoding `name` in the `__str__` method, but that's the default behavior if `__unicode__` is correctly defined.

Answer (score 2):

When using Python 2.7, you need to override your Model's `__unicode__`'s methods, not `__str__`. Django will take care of unicode decoding using UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but for those using django under python 2.x consider following [django's recommended way to deal with `__str__` and `__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).

This not only favors portability of your django project from python 2.x to 3.x but it should fix most of the issues associated to encoding.

Here is how the **models.py** should be adapted to follow django's recommended way using a decorator:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_id = models.ForeignKey('CategoryType')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*Hope that is helpful and happy coding!*